# Justify manual line breaks at the bottom of a column

Tags: line-breaking, two-column, multicol, columnbreak

I'm trying to [reproduce a justified multi-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276759/22603), and am therefore using manual line breaks throughout.  However, this doesn't work for lines at the bottom of a column, because `\linebreak` inserts a blank line at the bottom of the column:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this\linebreak\columnbreak

\noindent continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that ``all men are created equal.''
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above example, showing an extra blank line at the bottom of the first column]

Leaving the `\linebreak` off also doesn't work; while a bare `\columnbreak` doesn't insert the extra blank line, it fails to justify the broken line.

[image: Output of above example, showing the last line of the first column unjustified]

A crude workaround is to omit `\linebreak` and manually replace all spaces on the last line with `{\hfill}`.  However, this is inconvenient and probably suppresses use of stretched inter-letter spacing for justification.

Note that while I am using the `multicol` package and breaking columns with `\columnbreak`, the same problem exists when using a regular `twocolumn` document and breaking columns with `\pagebreak`.

How can I make `\linebreak` suppress the blank line at the end of the column, or force `\columnbreak`/`\pagebreak` to justify the lines they break?

Comment: You should not have `\linebreak` at all, since you have followed it by a paragraph break, but since it logically isn't a paragraph break it would be more natural to have just `\columnbreak` But it is not at all clear why you are doing manual line and column breaking at all?

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to reproduce an existing (paper) document, so I want all the line and column breaks to match.

Comment: ah that's what you meant by `reporoduce` I didn't catch that:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want a paragraph break at that point, certainly you never want `\linebreak` at the end of a paragraph, so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this\columnbreak\linebreak{}
continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty,
 and dedicated to the proposition that ``all men are created equal.''
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or in this case, just omit `\columnbreak{}` as well, producing the same output.

Comment: I see!  It had never occurred to me to add `{}` to the end of `\columnbreak`.  Can you explain why it's necessary?  (The reason I added the paragraph break to begin with was that using `\columnbreak` by itself didn't work at all.)

Comment: Also, I just tested this answer and while it seems to work in the MWE from my question, it doesn't work in my real-world example.  The `\columnbreak{}` gets ignored, at least in some sense—rather than breaking the column where I put it, the column gets broken several words later.  Do you know what might be causing this or do I need to revise my example?

Comment: @Psychonaut as always a space after a comandname doesn't produce a space token, it simply terminates the command, but you want a space token here. same as if you need to do `\LaTeX{} ` if you want a space token.

Comment: @Psychonaut `\columnbreak` in horizontal mode is like `\pagebreak` and does not affect the linebreaking at all- the line breaks where it breaks and then the column break is inserted after that line. If you also want to force linebreak then use `\columnbreak\linebreak{}`

Comment: Yes, `\columnbreak\linebreak` works for me.  Thanks!  (In my earlier comment I misinterpreted the `{}` as being responsible for correcting the behaviour I was complaining about.  In my real-world document it's not necessary as I'm breaking a column at a hyphen.)

Comment: @Psychonaut I added `\linebreak` to the answer